# Errors in Zend framework navigation , can someone help?

Tags: php, zend-framework, navigation

http://site2.example.com/
Error=>

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/site/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml on line 19 Call Stack: 0.0003 335220 
1. {main}() /var/www/site/public/index.php:0 0.0710 4242640
2. Zend_Application->run() /var/www/site/public/index.php:26 0.0710 4242640
3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Application.php:366 0.0711 4242712
4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php:97 0.1046 5601136
5. Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->postDispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:965 0.1046 5601136
6. Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout->postDispatch() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php:331 0.1048 5601500
7. Zend_Layout->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Layout/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php:143 0.1056 5605568
8. Zend_View_Abstract->render() /var/www/site/library/Zend/Layout.php:796 0.1057 5646952
9. Zend_View->_run() /var/www/site/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:880 0.1060 5662656
10. include('/var/www/site/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml') /var/www/site/library/Zend/View.php:108
```

This is the code =>

```
<head>
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jwplayer.js'); ?>
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/swfobject.js'); ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/topmenu.css'); ?>
</head>

<?php
    $flXml=new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
    $container = new Zend_Navigation($flXml);
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Navigation', $container);
?>

<div id="nav-menu">
    <?php
        $obj_menuacl=new Model_MenuAcl();

        $_auth=Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setAcl($obj_menuacl)->setRole($_auth->getStorage()->read()->uid);
        echo $this->loggedInAs();
        echo '<br><br>';
        echo 'You are in: ' . $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setLinkLast(false)->setMinDepth(0)->render();
    ?>
</div>
<div class="mainbody"><?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?></div>
<br />
```

What should i do ?

Where is the error ?

This is the line number 19 =>

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setAcl($obj_menuacl)->setRole($_auth->getStorage()->read()->uid);
```

If i try to print it=> echo $_auth->getStorage(); <=it results that error message.

Comment: You're asking loads of easy ZF questions at the moment. My guess is, you haven't worked through the beginners tutorials and you are not working with the manual and the quick start properly! Maybe you should do that instead of flooding SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say it was this

```
$_auth->getStorage()->read()->uid
```

as this is the only attempt to get a class property on that line (everything else is a method).

It seems that whatever is returned by `Zend_Auth_Storage_Interface::read()` is not an object. As this is something you set in your own code, I cannot offer any further advice other than to debug the return value of `read()`.

### Update

I'd attempt to fix it like this but without knowing more about your application, I'm only guessing.

```
$_auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

$uid = $_auth->hasIdentity() ? $_auth->getIdentity()->uid : null;

echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setAcl($obj_menuacl)->setRole($uid);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can i debug to see the result ? Is there any function like debug($variable); ?

Comment: @guru, either use `var_dump($_auth->getStorage()->read())` or `Zend_Debug::dump($_auth->getStorage()->read())` then look at the HTML-Source. But you have to comment out any code that might raise a Fatal error (that means at least line 19).

Comment: Zend_Debug::dump($_auth->getStorage()->read());  results NULL

Comment: @guru If `read()` is returning `null`, it means you haven't stored anything in your auth storage. You can't expect to retrieve the `uid` property of *nothing*

Comment: So what should i do ? How should i change that line of code if nothing is stored or if it's NULL?